# SQLite - Small transactions better in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sqlite, io, multiprocessing, hard-drive

Using `sqlite3` from python, I recently changed my writes from something like

```
for x in X:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?)",x)
```

to bulk inserts like

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?)",(x for x in X))
```

It is the case that I am running multiple instances of this code in parallel on separate cores. Each process has its own input file and output database.

The processes are not running at 100% due to I/O being at the maximum. It might have worked better before I changed the code but I am really not sure.

Now I am wondering if in the case of parallel processing, it could be better for I/O to do many small insertions as opposed to few larger ones, as write access is blocked for a smaller time in the first case, and therefore the input to the hard drive is more 'liquid' and can be managed better?

Comment: What are the results of your measurements?

Comment: You got me there. I don't have any measurements. It is a large-scale computation that takes now around 24h. Unfortunately I don't remember how long it took before I changed the code and also I doubled the number of processes which was perhaps not a good idea either because now it's really I/O bound. There was also perhaps more activity from other users on the server the last time... So it's really more of a theoretical question to be honest.

Comment: In theory, it could go either way.

Comment: It's good to know that there is a chance that single transactions are better in multiprocessing.